# KEYDOWN in Firemonkey [ CTRL and "+" ]

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to detect the key combination CTRL and "+" sign simultaneously, sure there is a way, but I can not find the virtual code VK of the "+" sign anywhere, except the unique code of numeric keyboard **vkAdd**.

For example, for the general sign "-", we have **Vkminus** and for the numeric keyboard **vkSubtract**. *How would it be for the plus sign?*

```
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (Key = vkminus) then // sign "-" ok ! 
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (Key = ¿?) then // sign "+" :-(
```

Comment: You have deleted your question regarding transparent `StringGrid`. It is a pitty, because I've been trying different means and found a simple way of making the grid transparent. If you are still interested, please undelete [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59086807/2292722) and leave me a notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `$BB` :

```
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (Key = $BB) then
```

---

`VK_OEM_PLUS` Defined in Windows unit.

```
{$EXTERNALSYM VK_OEM_PLUS}
VK_OEM_PLUS = 187;
{$EXTERNALSYM VK_OEM_MINUS}
VK_OEM_MINUS = 189;
```