# Transparent background TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

The question is about creating a transparent background in the TStringGrid control. The idea was to modify the white color that is created by default in the grid and use a null color, but I have not succeeded. I share here what has been done so far.

[image]

After researching the issue, I was able to show some transperence in the StringGrid by modifying the opacity property, through "Edit Custum Style" in the Background section. This solution is not perfect because it affects the associated TScrollBox control, but at least it is a first approach.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you want to shine through, image or ...? Or do you just want it to have the same color as the form behind?

Comment: Typically done not necessarily by adding transparency, but rather by drawing something onto its canvas, which could be an image of whatever's behind the grid. On that note, it could get tricky, since the custom drawing mechanism expects you to draw one cell at a time. So, keep the full image cached, then when drawing each cell, copy the contents required for that cell rect.

Comment: Hi Tom, The TStringrid is drawn on a firemonkey frame and this on a form. I can change the color of the cells, but I can not remove the white background color on which they are drawn, should be a null color (transparent; TAlphaColors.null), showing only the grid text and separator lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design of the FMX TStringGrid has no property to make it transparent. However, using styles, transparency can be achieved. You don't need to use styles on the whole application if you don't want to, but you can if you do.

The solution is a simple setting in the style of the grid according to following:

Add a `TStringGrid` to an `Fmx` form

- Right click the grid and select `Edit Default style`
- The style editor opens. In `structure` select `gridstyle - background - content`
- In the properties of `content`, locate `ClipParent` and set to `True`
- Click on `Apply and Close` to close the style editor

You now have a grid where the area under the header is transparent. If you have more rows (default is 100) than fits, you will also have the scrollbar on the right.

You can remove the header by setting `Options.Header = False` in `TStringGrid` properties.

[image]

---

I just noticed that you have found some solution too, however relying on `Opacity` settings can be tricky, because it affects potentially also other parts of the grid, perhaps in your case, if you select the `content` and adjust its opacity?.

Comment: you approach is the most appropriate and gives a good solution, also solving the problem of the first approach using Opacity. My vote for you. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome, you too deserved a uv. It also seems your previous dv has disappeared. Great!

Comment: Due in large part to your interest in rescuing this issue!. Thank you for the redemption to all :-).